Problem in Finding Difference in Telescopic Series
I had the following question in an exam:
$\dfrac{1}{2×4×6×8}+\dfrac{1}{4×6×8×10}+\dfrac{1}{6×8×10×12}...+\dfrac{1}{18×20×22×24}=?$
I thought I could find the answer using telescopic series but there are four factors and if I try combining any two factors, the difference becomes unequal for the terms. Is my thinking correct and if yes, how do I proceed.
Detailed solutions are welcome.

Numerical evidence suggests that the result is 73 / 21120  where $21120 = 2^7 . 3 . 5 . 11$

$$S=\frac{1}{16}\sum_{n=1}^{9}\dfrac{1}{n(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)}$$
$$S=\frac{1}{48}\sum_{n=1}^{9}\dfrac{(n+3)-(n)}{n(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)}$$
$$S=\frac{1}{48}\left[\sum_{n=1}^{9}\dfrac{1}{n(n+1)(n+2)}-\dfrac{1}{(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)}\right]=\frac{73}{21120}$$
(From the comments) If your sum was, $$S=\frac{1}{16}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{1}{n(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)}=\frac{1}{288}=\frac{1}{2^53^2}$$
Extras -
To telescope consecutive factors in denominator, create the difference of the largest and smallest term in the numerator and proceed (refer above)
To telescope consecutive factors in numerator, create the difference of the factor succeeding and preceding the largest and smallest term respectively in the numerator and proceed (refer below)
$$S=\sum_{n=1}^{k}{n(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)}$$
$$S=\frac15\sum_{n=1}^{k}((n+4)-(n-1)){n(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)}$$
$$S=\frac15\sum_{n=1}^{k}{n(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)(n+4)-(n-1)n(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)}$$
$$S=\frac{k(k+1)(k+2)(k+3)(k+4)}{5}$$

The initial factor is 1/16, not 1/2. The final result is 73/21120

+1 Same result but simpler method than my initial suggestion (partial fractions, like Claude just did) in the (now self-deleted) first comment to the OP.

Hint
I think that you could consider each denominator as
$$\prod_{n=1}^4 2(n+p)$$ and using partial fraction decomposition
$$a_p=\frac 1 {\prod_{n=1}^4 2(n+p)}$$ $$a_p= \frac{1}{96 (p+1)}-\frac{3}{96 (p+2)}+\frac{3}{96(p+3)}-\frac{1}{96 (p+4)}$$  which shows the telescoping.
Making the problem more general, you need to compute
$$S_m=\sum_{p=0}^m a_p$$ which has a very simple closed form in term of $m$.

So it is $\frac1{96}$ times $\frac12+\frac13+\frac14-\frac1{11}-\frac1{12}-\frac1{13}-\frac33+\frac3{12}$... ?still difficult to compute.

@BobDobbs. Don't you see the telescoping ? As I wrote, for any $m$ the formula is more than simple (ratio of two cubic polynomials)
